# How do I identify the type of variable in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, imputation

I am trying to create a comprehensive automated code for my team for missing value imputation using several different methods. I know the logic but I am having trouble in the data class identification which is important in deciding which method to chose for imputation.

The data that am working on looks like this:
[image]

Now, I want my code to identify the type of variables as:

1. Categorical/Factor with multiple levels
2. Factor with two levels 1 and 0(binary)
3. Factor with two levels except 1 and 0, like 'yes' and 'no'
4. Continuous

Here is the WIP code that I have but it isn't doing the job well and I understand the logic will fail given the data is different

```
data_type_vector<-function(x)
{
  categorical_index<-character()
  binary_index<-character()
  continuous_index<-character()
  binary_index_1<-character()

  data<-x

  for(a in 1:ncol(data)){

if(length(unique(data[,a])) >= 2 & length(unique(data[,a])) < 15 & 
   max(as.character(data[,a]),na.rm=T) != 1 & min(as.character(data[,a]),na.rm=T) !=0)
{

  categorical_index<-c(categorical_index,colnames(data[a]))

} else if (max(as.character(data[,a]),na.rm=T) == 1 & min(as.character(data[,a],na.rm=T))==0) {

  binary_index<-c(binary_index,colnames(data[a]))

} else if (length(unique(data[,a]))==2) {

  #this basically defines categorical variables with two categories like male/female
  #which don't have 1 0 values in the data but are still binary
  #we are keeping them seperate for the purpose of further analysis

  binary_index_1<-c(binary_index_1,colnames(data[a]))

} else

{
  continuous_index<-c(continuous_index,colnames(data[a]))
}

}

assign("categorical_index",categorical_index,envir=globalenv())
assign("binary_index",binary_index,envir=globalenv())
assign("continuous_index",continuous_index,envir=globalenv())
assign("binary_index_1",binary_index_1,envir=globalenv())
}
```

I am trying to improve the logics that I have used to make it generic so that others can use it but I have kind of hit a wall here. Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can just use `class()` and / or `str()` and some simple control flow statements

Comment: @Hack-R It doesn't works the way I intend the result to.

Comment: Pictures aren't code/data. They're for charts.

Comment: See [mcve] on how to post reproduciuble examples to SO.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I'll keep that in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by checking the number of levels and the levels themselves.  `categorize` is the generic that invokes `categorize.data.frame` if given a data.frame.  It in turn invokes `categorize.default` for each column. `categorize` can also directly be called on a column.

The way it works is that it computes the number of levels except if there are three or more it uses 3 and it adds on 2 if the levels are "0" and "1".  This gives us a number between 0 and 4 inclusive.  Then we set  up a factor with meaningful level names.

Note that anything that is not a factor will be identified as "continuous".  For example, as implied by the question, a column containing just 0's and 1's is continuous as it is not a factor.

```
categorize <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("categorize")

categorize.data.frame <- function(x, ...) sapply(x, categorize)

categorize.default <- function(x, ...) {
   factor(min(nlevels(x), 3) + 2*identical(levels(x), c("0", "1")), levels = 0:4, 
    labels = c("continuous", "factor1", "factor2", "factor", "zero-one"))
}
```

Now test it out:

```
DF <- data.frame(a = factor(c(0, 1, 0)), b = factor(c("male", "female", "male")), 
         c = factor(1:3), d = 1:3)

categorize(DF)
##          a          b          c          d 
##   zero-one    factor2     factor continuous 
## Levels: continuous factor1 factor2 factor zero-one

categorize(DF$a)
## [1] zero-one
## Levels: continuous factor1 factor2 factor zero-one

categorize(0:1)
## [1] continuous
## Levels: continuous factor1 factor2 factor zero-one
```

**Note:** Since what is being asked for is close to just asking for the number of levels, an alternative might be to just return the number of levels and use -2 to mean a binary factor with "0", "1" levels.  That is,

```
categorize.default <- function(x, ...) nlevels(x) - 4 * identical(levels(x), c("0", "1"))
```

Comment: That is a really good explanation and it makes total sense. So, if I use `categorize.default <- function(x, ...) nlevels(x) - 4 * identical(levels(x), c("0", "1"))` these are the values and meanings: _-2 : Binary(0 and 1)_,_0 : Continuous_,_1 : factor1_,_2 : factor2_,_>=3 : factor with multiple levels_. Am I correct?

Comment: If n is the value of the formula in your comment then n = 2 means 2 levels, n = 3 means 3 levels, n = 4 levels, etc.  Use the `min(nlevels(x), 3) - 4 * identical(levels(x), c("0", "1"))` if you want 3 to mean 3 or more levels but I am not so sure there is really any advantage in cutting it off at 3 like that.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you so much for the solution.